# How to count rows which are divided into other variables as a whole?

Tags: sql, derby

This way i get one river and all provinces it flows through are counted:

```
SELECT Geo_River.RIVER, COUNT(Geo_River.COUNTRY)
FROM Geo_River
GROUP BY Geo_River.RIVER
```

This way i get the same river multiple times and it counts for every country the provinces the river flows thorugh together:

```
SELECT Geo_River.RIVER, COUNT(Geo_River.COUNTRY)
FROM Geo_River
GROUP BY Geo_River.RIVER, Geo_River.COUNTRY
```

I want to count the countries the river flows through but some country are divided into different provinces. 
If so the country should be count as one and not by number of provinces.

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 Code VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT CountryKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Capital VARCHAR(40),
 Province VARCHAR(40),
 Area INTEGER CONSTRAINT CountryArea
   CHECK (Area >= 0),
 Population INTEGER CONSTRAINT CountryPop
   CHECK (Population >= 0));
```

```
CREATE TABLE geo_River
(River VARCHAR(40) , 
 Country VARCHAR(4) ,
 Province VARCHAR(40) ,
 CONSTRAINT GRiverKey PRIMARY KEY (Province ,Country, River) );
```

Comment: Tables have _columns_ not "variables"

Comment: just count the distinct countries in your first query: COUNT(DISTINCT Geo_River.COUNTRY)

Comment: Thanks it didnt know thas was possible.

Comment: I use Apache-Netbeans and i think the databases are created as a JAVA-DB do you mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `distinct` within `count`. Also if you are not doing a join then no need to provide table name before columns.

```
SELECT 
  RIVER, 
  COUNT(distinct COUNTRY)
FROM Geo_River
GROUP BY 
  RIVER
```

Comment: I didnt know i could use distinct in count so i thought maybe i need joins and thats why i provided the table names.

Comment: Why grouping by COUNTRY ?

Answer (score 2):

Please provide example input and output as the question is not very clear.

This does not make sense:

```
SELECT Geo_River.RIVER, COUNT(Geo_River.COUNTRY)
FROM Geo_River
GROUP BY Geo_River.RIVER, Geo_River.COUNTRY
```

Do you need to count the different countries the river is flowing through and you are not able to do that straight-forward as one country would have many provinces ?

Does something like this work,

```
SELECT Geo_River.RIVER, COUNT(distinct Geo_River.COUNTRY) as n_countries
FROM Geo_River
GROUP BY Geo_River.RIVER
```

Assuming : SQL = MySQL.

Comment: Problem is solved already i just didnt know that i could use distinct in count.